# Unable to return data from postgres using Spring and JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

1. I created a postgresql database with a table, two columns, and some data. 
   [postgresql db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxczC.jpg)
2. I created a new spring package using start.spring.io.  [start.spring.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVk3s.jpg)
3. I imported the project into Eclipse and created a few classes.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

**HelpdeskApplication.java (runner)**

```
package com.taidiagnostics.helpdesk;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelpdeskApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelpdeskApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Person.java (domain)**

```
package com.taidiagnostics.helpdesk.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

**PersonRepository.java (repository)**

```
package com.taidiagnostics.helpdesk.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.taidiagnostics.helpdesk.domain.Person;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findAll();

}
```

**PersonController (controller)**

```
package com.taidiagnostics.helpdesk.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.taidiagnostics.helpdesk.domain.Person;
import com.taidiagnostics.helpdesk.repository.PersonRepository;


@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/person")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

4. Everything appears to work, but when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/person, empty {} are returned.

What configuration(s) / annotation(s) am I missing?

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your screenshot I can see that you're using `helpdesk` name of the DB.
Meanwhile your properties file tells me that you're trying to connect to `postgres` DB

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

Please make sure that the name is correct. 
It may be that `person` table was created in the `postgres` DB

Comment: THANK YOU!  ARG!